# How can I run a powershell that looks for a string with random numbers in the string and replace it?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

So I am tasked with looking through all of the html content areas in my content tree and look for this string:

```
"<div id="fpCE_version" style="display:none;">8.5.1</div>"
```

However the version changes with numbers so this 8.5.1 could be 8.5.7 or 8.4.2, so I need a way of looking for that div and replace it with nothing. Here is what I have for only finding the one version so need help with either regex or any other ideas. Thanks

```
foreach ($item in $itemsToProcess) {
    $items = Get-ItemField $item
    foreach($field in $items){
     $html = $item.Text
     if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($html)) { continue }
        $newText = $html.Replace('<div id="fpCE_version" style="display:none;">8.5.7</div>', '')
        $item.Text = $newText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check with where condition on the id of the HTML tag and replace that with an empty string.

```
if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($html)) { continue }
$divTag = $html.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where { $_.id -eq 'fpCE_version' }
if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($divTag)) 
{
  $newText = $html.Replace($divTag, '')
  $item.Text = $newText
}
```

If you want to check with the id:

```
if($html_.id -eq `fpCE_version`)
{
  $item.Text = ''
}
```

If you want to check with the class name:
`$html_.className -eq 'your class name'`

You can also match with the inner text of the HTML tag:

```
if ($html.innertext -match "8.") 
{
  $item.Text = ''
}
```

Comment: I need to keep the remainder of my text that is in these HTML fields. This is just a div at the bottom that I need removed out of the html and leave the other contents alone.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following script which uses `Regex`.

If searches for exact `<div id="fpCE_version" style="display:none;">` and removes everything from that div, without checking what's inside (assuming there is no other div inside that div).

```
$regex = '<div id="fpCE_version" style="display:none;">[^<]*</div>'

$fieldsToCheck = @('Text', 'Text 2')

foreach ($item in $itemsToProcess) {
  foreach($field in $fieldsToCheck){
    $html = $item[$field]

    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($html)) { 
      continue
    }

    if ($html.Contains('fpCE_version')) {
      $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
      $item[$field] = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($html, $regex, '')
      $item.Editing.EndEdit() | out-null
    }
  }
}
```